# Random "int is not subscriptable" behaviour

Tags: python, json, exception, dictionary, casting

I'm reading a valid JSON file (nested 5 levels deep), then adding some data to it, and subsequently trying to use that data for some calculations.

I'm getting `int is not subscriptable` errors in a random fashion. I can't wrap my head around it. casting to `str()` doesn't help, printing with `pprint` doesn't alleviate it, casting to `int()` on input doesn't help either. I'm desperately running out of options...

**main function**

```
with open(rNgram_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as ngram_file:
    data = json.load(ngram_file)
    data = rank_items(data)
    data = probability_items(data)
```

**rank_items(data)**

All the values are counted at the 5-nested level, and added working upwards in the tree. I added the `int()` cast to the input as a possible solution, but that didn't help. *The issue occurs with getting the `x_grams['_rank']`*

```
for ngram, one_grams in data.items():
        ngram_rank = 0
        for one_gram, two_grams in one_grams.items():
            one_gram_rank = 0
           [..]
                for four_gram, values in four_grams.items():
                # 4gram = of, values = 34
                three_gram_rank += values
                four_grams['_rank'] = int(three_gram_rank)
                two_gram_rank += three_gram_rank
           [..]    
            two_grams['_rank'] = int(one_gram_rank)
            ngram_rank += one_gram_rank
        one_grams['_rank'] = int(ngram_rank)
```

**probability_items(data)**

This is where the errors occur. Seemingly at random, it will complain about `int is not subscriptable` where `x_rank` or `x_grams['rank]` are being printed or assigned, even if they are evaluated with `type()` (which, if it works, says `<class 'int'>`) 
I marked the most common lines with a comment below.
Weirdly enough, line 2 and 3 never raise an exception...

```
    for ngram, one_grams in data.items():
        ngram_rank = int(one_grams['_rank'])               # never gives an error
        print("NgramRank: ", str(ngram_rank))              # never gives an error
        if ngram != '_rank':
            for one_gram, two_grams in one_grams.items():
                pprint(type(two_grams['_rank']))             # common error point
                one_gram_rank = str(two_grams['_rank'])      # never reaches this
                if one_gram != '_rank':
                    for two_gram, three_grams in two_grams.items():
                        pprint(type(three_grams['_rank']))   # common error point
                        pprint(str(three_grams['_rank']))    # never reaches this
                        two_gram_rank = str(three_grams['_rank'])
                        [..]
                    one_gram_prob = int(one_gram_rank) / int(ngram_rank)
                    two_grams['_prob'] = one_gram_prob
            ngram_prob = int(ngram_rank) / int(ngram_rank)
            one_grams['_prob'] = ngram_prob
```

In randowm fashion, an exception is thrown on the common error point above. Because of these exceptions, the lines below is never reached. But if you delete the common error points, the lines below become the error points.
And sometimes, It does a full run through all the way in the inner-for-loop, printing `<class 'int'>` when evaluated, and all, until it halts at an exception.

I have no clue what's happening, I don't even understand how this error can occur when i'm evaluating it with `Type()`

Since this is a weird issue, and I'm obviously making a weird mistake, I put all the code in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/puredevotion/7922480

Hope someone can help!

**TraceBack details**

```
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "Ngram_ranking.py", line 121, in probability_items\n    pprint(type(four_grams[\'_rank\']))\n', "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable\n"]

*** extract_tb:
[('Ngram_ranking.py', 121, 'probability_items', "pprint(type(four_grams['_rank']))")]

*** format_tb:
['  File "Ngram_ranking.py", line 121, in probability_items\n    pprint(type(four_grams[\'_rank\']))\n']

*** tb_lineno: 121
Exception in on line 121: pprint(type(four_grams['_rank'])): 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

**TraceBack for line 115**

```
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "Ngram_ranking.py", line 115, in probability_items\n    pprint(type(three_grams[\'_rank\']))\n', "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable\n"]

*** extract_tb:
[('Ngram_ranking.py', 115, 'probability_items', "pprint(type(three_grams['_rank']))")]

*** format_tb:
['  File "Ngram_ranking.py", line 115, in probability_items\n    pprint(type(three_grams[\'_rank\']))\n']

*** tb_lineno: 115
Exception in on line 115: pprint(type(three_grams['_rank'])): 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

**PPRINT(data) at the top of probability_items(data)**

```
{'aesthetic': {'_rank': 290,
           'feeling': {'_rank': 10,
                       'the': {'_rank': 10,
                               'feeling': {'_rank': 10, 'of': 10}}},
           'perception': {'_rank': 280,
                          'and': {'_rank': 190,
                                  'the': {'_rank': 190,
                                          'design': 15,
                                          'environment': 5,
                                          'music': 100,
                                          'painting': 15,
                                          'work': 5,
                                          'works': 50}},
                          'of': {'_rank': 90,
                                 'the': {'_rank': 50,
                                         'work': 30,
                                         'world': 20},
                                 'their': {'_rank': 40, 'female': 40}}}}}
```

Comment: Can you give complete stacktrace?

Comment: @thefourtheye edited the post, now with tracebacks (borrowed the tb-code from: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/traceback.html)

Comment: Suggestion: each time you do `pprint(type(x_grams['_rank']))` you precede it with `pprint(type(x_grams))` just to verify what type `x_grams` is before you attempt to subscript it. It seems as though there is some place in the code where you are assigning an int to one of the `x_grams` values where you only mean to assign a dict, but it's not clear where.

Comment: For that matter, do `if type(x_grams) != dict:` to pprint x_grams before you attempt to subscript it. Or just `pprint(data)` before you do anything, so you can examine the whole structure to see where the errant ints are.

Comment: Have you tried running the code in an interactive debugger?

Comment: @Kimvais There's an interactive debugger for python?

Comment: @puredevotion http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have a multi-level nested dictionary and you replicate the same code for all the three levels despite nesting being somewhat different.

I'll just take some part of your dictionary

```
{
'aesthetic': 
    {
    '_rank': 290,
    'feeling': 
        {
        '_rank': 10,
        'the': 
            {
            '_rank': 10,
            'feeling': 
                {
                '_rank': 10, 
                'of': 10
                }
            }
         },
    }
}
```

Your top level dictionary is uniform as the value (for key `aesthetic`) is *always* a dictionary. But the lower levels also have `ints` as some of their values.

Thus when you do

```
for ngram, one_grams in data.items():
```

you have `ngram=aesthetics` and `one_grams={the dictionary}`

```
int(one_grams['_rank'])
```

Will always work (as the value dictionary has the element `_rank`. So you never get an error here.

Now we move to the next step

```
one_gram, two_grams in one_grams.items()
```

Running `.items()` for `one_grams` dictionary gives

```
(one_gram,two_grams) = [('_rank', 290), ('feeling', {'_rank': 10, 'the': {'_rank': 10, 'feeling': {'_rank': 10, 'of': 10}}})]
```

Notice `two_grams` is an `int` for the first entry and a `dict` for the second. Since you iterate over the entire items() while doing

```
two_grams['_rank']
```

you run into the error (which tells you that you've hit an `int` when `dict` was expected). The same problem occurs in the inner loops.

As dictionaries are not ordered, items() can return in any order. Thus `_rank` may be the first element or below other dictionary elements. In that case you descend into the inner for loops and encounter the same problem there.

You can neglect `_rank` keys while iterating

```
for one_gram,two_grams one_grams.items(): 
    if one_gram=='_rank': 
        continue
```

in all the loops.

Comment: I though i had this already covered with `if ngram != '_rank':` but clearly not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @puredevotion Look at it this way: at some point in the loop `for one_gram, two_grams in one_grams.items():` you will find that `one_gram` is `'_rank'` and `two_grams` is an int. But you call `pprint(type(two_grams['_rank']))` before even checking to find out whether it is.